# Transfer Dates from Userform to Database (Including Day Name)

Tags: excel, vba

This may or may not be possible but i have two textboxes (textBox20 and Textbox21... yes, i will change their names soon) and after i click a button, a third textbox displays the difference between both dates on days format. (All good so far.)
What i want is to be able to insert inside the database or... in another textbox and send it later to the same database, **the day name which corresponds to each of both (textbox20 and textbox21), for example, if the day is: 20/02/2020, in the data base, it should show: thursday, 20/02/2020 or thursday, 20 of feb of 2020**. If i do this in the same box, i can´t use the datediff function, and its a mess... I want something simple to transfer to the database, so later i can search for it and display it on another textbox later on... (im doing a little database)

```
Private Sub TextBox20_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'check date format
   With TextBox20
        If IsDate(TextBox20.Text) Then           'Format as desired.
            TextBox20.Text = Format(TextBox20.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")

       Else
            TextBox20.Text = ""                  'Clear the TextBox
            MsgBox "Please use the following format: DD/MM/YYYY."
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

   End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'check date format
   With TextBox21
        If IsDate(TextBox21.Text) Then           'Format as desired.
            TextBox21.Text = Format(TextBox21.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")

       Else
            TextBox21.Text = ""                  'Clear the TextBox
            MsgBox "Please use the following format: DD/MM/YYYY."
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

   End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCal_Click()

TextBox22.Value = DateDiff("d", (TextBox20.Text), (TextBox21.Text))

End Sub
```

Comment: Should we read the code and deduce what is wrong? Do you receive an error? If yes, what error and at which row? If not, what is the returned data versus what has it to be? At what data base are you referring? Do your `Exit` events do their job? What does your last code line return? What instead of what?

Comment: I would firstly try replacing of `TextBox22.Value = DateDiff("d", (TextBox20.Text), (TextBox21.Text))` with `TextBox22.Value = DateDiff("d", DateValue(TextBox20.Text), DateValue(TextBox21.Text))`.

Comment: `DateDiff` function DOES NOT CARE about format! You **must supply it with Date variables**. If you have Date variables and need the result in days you simple can also use simple `DateValue(TextBox21.Text) - DateValue(TextBox20.Text)` or even `CLng(DateValue(TextBox21.Text)) - CLng(DateValue(TextBox20.Text))`. But you must assure yourself that you are vehiculate checked Date variables...

Comment: In your database, I would definitely add an additional field to hold the day name separately from the date (though storing the day name at all isn't really necessary, can always calculate as part of a query if necessary), and then on your Userform add additional textboxes specifically to hold the day names so that the date fields remain actual dates.  And then you can send the respective info to the database in their separate fields.  Maintains data integrity and prevents the "this isn't actually a date" issues.